# O que é e como funciona a função "clamp" no CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Recentemente tenho visto algumas pessoas falarem da função `clamp`.

Qual a sua real utilidade?

Há alguma relação com outras funções, como `max` ou `min`?

Comment: O clamp() é uma feature recente do CSS que permite definir um valor médio, entre um mínimo e máximo definido para um tamanho de fonte, por exemplo. Isso é uma mão na roda para sites responsivos. Nesse artigo [aqui](https://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/textos-responsivos-com-css-clamp/) vc pode ver melhor como faz para usar o clamp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O assunto é extenso porque podem ser muitas as variáveis, como tudo em CSS... Mas não é algo só para `font-size`.

O `clamp` na verdade é basicamente um *shorthand* para a construção de um valor "length" para o `font-size`, por exemplo, ou para o `width` de uma `div`.

Ele ajuda a incrementar o `min()` ou `max()` adicionando um ***entretanto*** entre um valor mínimo e máximo, ou seja, uma expressão como essa `width: clamp(200px, 50%, 600px);` significa que a `div` terá no máximo 600px, *entretanto*, ela não pode ter mais de 50% da largura do pai, e nem menos de 200px de largura.

Veja esse exemplo também em tela cheia para ver o comportamento:

```css
.box {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f00 0%, #000 100%);
  height: 100px;
  width: clamp(200px, 50%, 600px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium totam, accusamus eius assumenda odio nesciunt, corporis, cupiditate est architecto officiis minus? Inventore, non dicta! Eius doloribus placeat necessitatibus minima enim?</p>
```

`Clamp` está sendo aplicado amplamente no `font-size` porque ajuda a corrigir o problema de usar medidas baseadas no *view-port* no tamanho da fonte, onde em telas muito estreitas, por exemplo, uma medida como `font-size: 3vw` pode deixar o texto ilegível (já que `3VW` em uma tela de `320px` de largura corresponde aproximadamente a um `font-size` de `9px`). Então com `clamp` você pode fazer um mix do tipo `font-size: clamp(1.75rem, 3vw, 2.1rem);`

Repare nos valores das fontes abaixo e como se comporta a responsividade delas. A fonte com `clamp` vai atingir um valor mínimo que ainda permite a leitura, mesmo estando em `VW`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como você pode ver, o suporte dos browsers é até relativamente bom: https://caniuse.com/css-line-clamp

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Documentação da Mozilla sobre o clamp():**
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp

Dois artigos de referência que valem a pena!

https://css-tricks.com/min-max-and-clamp-are-css-magic/

https://medium.com/@Yuschick/fluid-typography-with-css-clamp-is-my-new-favorite-thing-573d0b8d7bfc